# PHP extract article excerpt from a page

Tags: php, facebook

anyone have any idea how to generate excerpt from any given article page (so could source from many type of sites)? Something like what facebook does when you paste a url into the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking to do is called [web scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping). The basic method for doing so would be to capture the page (you can scrape a URL using [`file_get_contents`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)), and then somehow parse it for the content that you want (ie. pull out content from the `<body>` tag).

In order to parse the returned HTML, you should use a DOM parser. PHP has its own [DOM classes](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/intro.dom.php) which you can use.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a video tutorial about how to do that:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-create-blog-excerpts-with-php/