# How do I get a teaser excerpt from a web article / user-posted link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-scraping

I have a site where users can submit content based on a link. Is there a way to detect the main content of the link and take a teaser? For example, on [Digg](http://www.digg.com), all of the entries have a small clip / excerpt from the link. That's pretty much exactly what I want.

I'm working with Ruby on Rails. I found [this question on extracting article excerpts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450764/php-extract-article-excerpt-from-a-page) but any tips in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that Digg uses the Open Graph Protocol (http://ogp.me/) by Facebook.

Ultimately, this was exactly what I was looking for!

The Ruby Gem OpenGraph:
https://github.com/intridea/opengraph

By accessing the metadata tag "description", I got the description e.g.

```
article = OpenGraph.fetch('http://www.page.com/article/1124')
article.description# => 'This is a small description of the movie'
```

Some pages (but not most articles) don't have the description.

Answer (score 0):

**How to Extract a Webpage’s Main Article Content**

Try extracting the text using DOM, here is an example page

```
<body>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/politics">Politics</a></li>
            <li><a href="/health">Health</a></li>
            <li><a href="/travel">Travel</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    <div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <p><b>MIAMI, Florida (CNN) </b> -- Hurricane Ike weakened slightly...
            <p>Ike hit Turks and Caicos Islands Sunday morning, leaving a trail of...
            <p>"It pretty much looks like an episode of 'The Twilight Zone,' " said...
            <p>Aftwood estimates at least 90 percent of homes he saw on the island were...
            <p>The possibility of similar devastation prompted state and local officials...
            <p > "Let's hope it's all a false alarm," Louisiana Gov. Bobby Jindal said...
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Some side-story that we don't really care about.</p>
            <p>Another paragraph for this story.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Yet another semi-related side-story that we still don't care about.</p>
            <p>Another paragraph for this story.</p>
            <p>Another paragraph for this story.</p>
            <p>Yet another paragraph for this story.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>© 2008 Cable News Network.<div>
</body>
```

Clearly, we don’t care about the navigation link text, or the two side-stories. Let’s break it down based on DOM location. We have six

tags in the first  tag of the second  tag of the body. We’ll represent this location as a list of indexes, like (2,1,*). If we group all the text nodes in this fashion, and track how much text each group contains, we get a table like:

```
location = characters
(1,1,1,1) = 4
(1,1,2,1) = 8
(1,1,3,1) = 6
(1,1,4,1) = 6
(1,1,5,1) = 5
(2,1,*) = 500
(2,2,*) = 100
(2,3,*) = 250
(3) = 26
```