# PHP Scrape Article Excerpt like Readability

Tags: php, web-scraping

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450764/php-extract-article-excerpt-from-a-page), but it doesn't really satisfy what I'm looking for. That question's answers were either: lift from the meta description tag, and the second was generating an excerpt for an article you already have the body from.

What I want to do is actually get the first few sentences of an *article*, like Readability does. What't the best method for this? HTML Parsing? Here's what I'm currently using, but this is not very reliable.

```
function guessExcerpt($url) {
    $html = file_get_contents_curl($url);

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);

    $metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

    for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
    {
        $meta = $metas->item($i);
        if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description')
            $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');

    }

    return $description;
}

function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: You can also give a look to [php-readability](http://code.fivefilters.org/php-readability/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a port of Readability in PHP: https://github.com/andreskrey/readability.php. Just try it. The extraction result will be similar to Readability (because it implements Readability's algorithm).

```
require 'lib/Readability.inc.php';

$html = file_get_contents_curl($url);

$Readability     = new Readability($html, $html_input_charset); // default charset is utf-8
$ReadabilityData = $Readability->getContent();

$title   = $ReadabilityData['title'];
$content = $ReadabilityData['content'];
```

Then you can use some sentences from `$content` as the excerpt.

Comment: Anybody know how to scrape a relavant thumbnail / image as well? Readability does exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Swivelgames Did you find out how to get thumbnail? I'd like to do something similar

Comment: @andrewliu The method I used to get a thumbnail is a tad bit more code. I used `preg_match_all` with `/<img.+src=([\'"])([^\'"]+)\1.*?\/?>/i` and built an array with all images. By parsing the `$url` in the example above, I was able to turn relative image paths into absolute paths by determining the baseurl. Then I present an array with absolute image paths to user to pick from. You can use a simple script to create thumbnails and save it on the web server to be displayed to the user, or scale using HTML. **Post a new question and paste the link here, and then I can give you specific code.**

Comment: @Swivelgames: could you get relavant image from page using this API?

Comment: @andrewliu: could you get relavant image from page using this API?

Comment: @Programming_crazy No, I was not. I had to write a little bit of extra code (abstracted in my comment above) in order to retrieve it. The solution I am using, however, is working quite well :) If you're curious as to how to use readability to retrieve all relevant images, post a new question and comment with the question's URL. I can then provide a good answer for it. And, please, I know I said to before, but do not use regular expressions to retrieve the images. It is a very, very bad practice.

Comment: @Swivelgames: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21201062/using-readability-api-to-scrape-most-relavant-image-from-page